# How do I pass the return data from a thread accessing a third-party service to the view dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net

In a web application we're making a feature is included where scanning documents will fill in specific fields in a form. A third-party service is taking care of the parsing of the images; the scanned documents get sent asynchronously.

In the registration page there is the additional condition that multiple individuals can be registered at once. The registration page has been designed so that additional forms can be added after the first; each form has a link to activate the scanning. The page is supposed to dynamically update, but we're having trouble checking when the 3rd-party service has returned the data and then passing the data to the view.

The page is using MVC 5 .NET. Clicking the link in the form triggers an ajax call for the scanning. We tried to have a continuous loop checking when data is returned from the third-party service but found out that if there is an error then the loop would continue indefinitely.

We're using this in the model:

```
public class RegulaReaderModel
{
    private RegulaReader m_RegulaReader = new RegulaReader();        

    public event EventHandler OnDataReady;        

    public void ConnectRegulaReader()
    {
        bool IsConnected = m_RegulaReader.Connected;
        if (!IsConnected)
        {
            m_RegulaReader.Connect();
            IsConnected = m_RegulaReader.Connected;
            if(!IsConnected)
            {
                //attempt to restart connection
                m_RegulaReader.Disconnect();
                m_RegulaReader.Connect();

                IsConnected = m_RegulaReader.Connected;
                if(IsConnected)
                {
                    InitializeRegulaReader();
                }
                else
                {
                    //error
                }
            }
            else
            {
                InitializeRegulaReader();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            InitializeRegulaReader();
        }            
    }

    public void InitializeRegulaReader()
    {
        m_RegulaReader.AutoScan = false;
        OnDataReady += rr_OnDataReady;
        m_RegulaReader.OnProcessingFinished += rr_OnProcessingFinished;                        
    }

    private void rr_OnDataReady(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Thread(ReadDataThread).Start();
    }

    void rr_OnProcessingFinished()
    {
        if (OnDataReady != null)
            OnDataReady(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private void ReadDataThread()
    {
        CaseMemberInfoModel caseMemberInfo = new CaseMemberInfoModel();
        int i;            
        XmlElement Item;
        XmlNodeList NoList;
        XmlDocument o = new XmlDocument();          

        // Getting text fields
        int total = m_RegulaReader.IsReaderResultTypeAvailable((int)eRPRM_ResultType.RPRM_ResultType_OCRLexicalAnalyze);

        if (total > 0)
        {
            o.LoadXml(m_RegulaReader.CheckReaderResultXML((int)eRPRM_ResultType.RPRM_ResultType_OCRLexicalAnalyze, 0, 0));

            NoList = o.GetElementsByTagName("Document_Field_Analysis_Info");

            for (i = 0; i < NoList.Count; i++)
            {
                Item = (XmlElement)NoList.Item(i);

                int FieldType = Convert.ToInt32(Item.GetElementsByTagName("Type").Item(0).InnerText);
                var FieldData = Item.GetElementsByTagName("Field_MRZ").Item(0).InnerText;

                //string DOB, lastname, firstname, middlename, nationality, sex, maritalStatus, cityOfBirth, countryOfBirth;
                switch (FieldType)
                {
                    case 5:
                        caseMemberInfo.BirthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(FieldData);                            
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        caseMemberInfo.LastName = FieldData;
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        caseMemberInfo.FirstName = FieldData;
                        break;
                    case 146:
                        caseMemberInfo.MiddleName = FieldData;
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        caseMemberInfo.Nationality = FieldData;
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        caseMemberInfo.Gender = FieldData;
                        break;
                    case 160:
                        caseMemberInfo.MaritalStatus = FieldData;
                        break;
                    case 261:
                        caseMemberInfo.BirthPlace = FieldData;
                        break;
                    case 263:
                        caseMemberInfo.BirthCountry = FieldData;
                        break;
                    default:
                        //do nothing
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        total = m_RegulaReader.IsReaderResultTypeAvailable((int)eRFID_ResultType.RFID_ResultType_RFID_BinaryData);
        if (total > 0)
        {
            XmlDocument rfidXML = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNodeList nodeList;
            XmlElement rfidItem;
            rfidXML.LoadXml(m_RegulaReader.CheckRFIDResultXML((int)eRFID_ResultType.RFID_ResultType_RFID_BinaryData, 0));
            nodeList = rfidXML.GetElementsByTagName("BirthdayPlace");
            //string placeOfBirth;
            if (nodeList != null)
            {
                rfidItem = (XmlElement)nodeList.Item(0);
                caseMemberInfo.BirthPlace = rfidItem.InnerText;
            }
        }

        //return caseMemberInfo;
    }

    public CaseMemberInfoModel ScanDocument()
    {
        CaseMemberInfoModel model = null;

        if(m_RegulaReader.Connected)
        {
            int returnCode = m_RegulaReader.GetImages();                                               
        }          

        return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: need code or something more specific. In what form is the data arriving in? Why not have a temp value updated upon new data arrival check if the temp value is correct(-1: no data or the data has been inserted in the view, 1: data arrived and ready to be passed to the view )

Comment: Have you looked at SignalR ?

Comment: Updated the post to include the code to access the 3rd-party service. We were initially using a purely client-side implementation with SignalR, but had trouble with getting the response from the 3rd-party service.